# TypeError using QueryLoader plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

For page loader i have used the plugin. Following is js:

```
var QueryLoader = {
    overlay: "",
    loadBar: "",
    preloader: "",
    items: new Array(),
    doneStatus: 0,
    doneNow: 0,
    selectorPreload: "body",
    ieLoadFixTime: 2000,
    ieTimeout: "",

    init: function() {
        if (navigator.userAgent.match(/MSIE (\d+(?:\.\d+)+(?:b\d*)?)/) == "MSIE 6.0,6.0") {
            //break if IE6          
            return false;
        }
        if (QueryLoader.selectorPreload == "body") {
            QueryLoader.spawnLoader();
            QueryLoader.getImages(QueryLoader.selectorPreload);
            QueryLoader.createPreloading();
        } else {
            $(document).ready(function() {
                QueryLoader.spawnLoader();
                QueryLoader.getImages(QueryLoader.selectorPreload);
                QueryLoader.createPreloading();
            });
        }

        //help IE drown if it is trying to die :)
        QueryLoader.ieTimeout = setTimeout("QueryLoader.ieLoadFix()", QueryLoader.ieLoadFixTime);
    },

    ieLoadFix: function() {
        var ie = navigator.userAgent.match(/MSIE (\d+(?:\.\d+)+(?:b\d*)?)/);
        if (ie[0].match("MSIE")) {
            while ((100 / QueryLoader.doneStatus) * QueryLoader.doneNow < 100) {
                QueryLoader.imgCallback();
            }
        }
    },

    imgCallback: function() {
        QueryLoader.doneNow ++;
        QueryLoader.animateLoader();
    },

    getImages: function(selector) {
        var everything = $(selector).find("*:not(script)").each(function() {
            var url = "";

            if ($(this).css("background-image") != "none") {
                var url = $(this).css("background-image");
            } else if (typeof($(this).attr("src")) != "undefined" && $(this).attr("tagName").toLowerCase() == "img") {
                var url = $(this).attr("src");
            }

            url = url.replace("url(\"", "");
            url = url.replace("url(", "");
            url = url.replace("\")", "");
            url = url.replace(")", "");

            if (url.length > 0) {
                QueryLoader.items.push(url);
            }
        });
    },

    createPreloading: function() {
        QueryLoader.preloader = $("<div></div>").appendTo(QueryLoader.selectorPreload);
        $(QueryLoader.preloader).css({
            height:     "0px",
            width:      "0px",
            overflow:   "hidden"
        });

        var length = QueryLoader.items.length; 
        QueryLoader.doneStatus = length;

        for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            var imgLoad = $("<img></img>");
            $(imgLoad).attr("src", QueryLoader.items[i]);
            $(imgLoad).unbind("load");
            $(imgLoad).bind("load", function() {
                QueryLoader.imgCallback();
            });
            $(imgLoad).appendTo($(QueryLoader.preloader));
        }
    },

    spawnLoader: function() {
        if (QueryLoader.selectorPreload == "body") {
            var height = $(window).height();
            var width = $(window).width();
            var position = "fixed";
        } else {
            var height = $(QueryLoader.selectorPreload).outerHeight();
            var width = $(QueryLoader.selectorPreload).outerWidth();
            var position = "absolute";
        }
        var left = $(QueryLoader.selectorPreload).offset()['left'];
        var top = $(QueryLoader.selectorPreload).offset()['top'];

        QueryLoader.overlay = $("<div></div>").appendTo($(QueryLoader.selectorPreload));
        $(QueryLoader.overlay).addClass("QOverlay");
        $(QueryLoader.overlay).css({
            position: position,
            top: top,
            left: left,
            width: width + "px",
            height: height + "px"
        });

        QueryLoader.loadBar = $("<div></div>").appendTo($(QueryLoader.overlay));
        $(QueryLoader.loadBar).addClass("QLoader");

        $(QueryLoader.loadBar).css({
            position: "relative",
            top: "50%",
            width: "0%"
        });
    },

    animateLoader: function() {
        var perc = (100 / QueryLoader.doneStatus) * QueryLoader.doneNow;
        if (perc > 99) {
            $(QueryLoader.loadBar).stop().animate({
                width: perc + "%"
            }, 500, "linear", function() { 
                QueryLoader.doneLoad();
            });
        } else {
            $(QueryLoader.loadBar).stop().animate({
                width: perc + "%"
            }, 500, "linear", function() { });
        }
    },

    doneLoad: function() {
        //prevent IE from calling the fix
        clearTimeout(QueryLoader.ieTimeout);

        //determine the height of the preloader for the effect
        if (QueryLoader.selectorPreload == "body") {
            var height = $(window).height();
        } else {
            var height = $(QueryLoader.selectorPreload).outerHeight();
        }

        //The end animation, adjust to your likings
        $(QueryLoader.loadBar).animate({
            height: height + "px",
            top: 0
        }, 500, "linear", function() {
            $(QueryLoader.overlay).fadeOut(800);
            $(QueryLoader.preloader).remove();
        });
    }
}
```

In my html file, I used following Javascript:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    QueryLoader.init();
</script>
```

And css is as following:

```
.QOverlay {
    background-color: #000000;
    z-index: 9999;
}

.QLoader {
    background-color: #CCCCCC;
    height: 1px;
}
```

I used this for simple example it works well.
But when I used this for my site it is giving error in js file as following:

> TypeError: $(...).offset(...) is undefined

```
var left = $(QueryLoader.selectorPreload).offset()['left'];
```

So please can you help out from this issue:
Thanks in advance..

Comment: dont paste all the code just explain your problem in few words and give some code sample, best practice is  setup a demo.

Comment: Offset is a JQuery Method, so 
in the line 

    `var left = $(QueryLoader.selectorPreload).offset()['left']`

if offset is undefined, you cant access to left property.
has included the jquery file?

If you are include the jQuery File.
`['left']` is better written in dot notation.
And are you sure the target element exist before getting offset ?

`$(QueryLoader.selectorPreload)` is the body element?

Answer (score 0):

Your plugin is not really one. Go see [the documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring) to see more details.

Anyway, even if it's not a plugin, it could work as an object using some jQuery functions.

First, you shouldn't call the object inside the object function. 
IE :

```
QueryLoader.ieTimeout = setTimeout("QueryLoader.ieLoadFix()", QueryLoader.ieLoadFixTime);
```

Here, you got your first error which you could have seen in the console. It should be :

```
this.ieTimeout = setTimeout(this.ieLoadFix, this.ieLoadFixTime);
```

You can start debugging like this, up to your initial error here.